# Read the longest string from an array in PHP 5.3

Tags: php, arrays

Here is part of the code.

```
$DatabaseArray=Array("Cooking","look","I cant","Walking the dog to the park","washing","talk","one");
  
$largest = max($DatabaseArray);
  
echo $largest. "<br />";
```

I would like to read the longest string from an array in PHP 5.3.0. I've tried the max function but doesnt seem to work as expected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$lengths = array_map('strlen', $DatabaseArray);
$maxLength = max($lengths);
$index = array_search($maxLength, $lengths);
echo $DatabaseArray[$index];
```

Comment: This code is returning the index rather than the longest the longest element in the array.

Comment: You are talking about line 3. The last line gives you the element itself.

Comment: Thanks man I hadn't noted because My database is very populated and there's no page break in your code. Thanks full time it's working!!!!

Answer (score 9):

```
$longestEntry = array_reduce($databaseArray, function ($a, $b) { return strlen($a) > strlen($b) ? $a : $b; });
```

(uses PHP 5.3 syntax)

You can't just use `max`, since that assumes all entries are numbers. Since they're strings though, *"the maximum string"* could mean anything, so you have to do manual comparison using `strlen`. The above `array_reduce` method with custom reduce function does such comparison and *reduces* the array to the longest member.

If you have *a lot* of entries (and I mean **a lot**, hundreds or thousands and up), it may not be very efficient, since it basically applies `strlen` twice to the whole array. If that's a problem, this is more efficient by applying `strlen` only once per string:

```
$longestEntry = current(array_reduce($databaseArray, function ($a, $b) {
    $b = array($b, strlen($b));
    return $a[1] > $b[1] ? $a : $b;
}, array(null, 0)));
```

Since you're calling it a `DatabaseArray` though: If this is coming from the database, you should make *it* do the work. It's probably going to be even more efficient. E.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(`string_col`) DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @deceze's answer, my suggestion is a single pass over the input array.  @KingCrunch's has a greater cost in terms of time complexity because it is using functions to traverse the data more *N* times.

Below has the same fundamental logic as @deceze's PHP snippet, but uses intuitive, individual variables instead of indexed elements for temporary storage.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/klOVj))

```
$maxLength = -1;
$longestValue = null;
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $length = strlen($value);
    if ($length > $maxLength) {
        $maxLength = $length;
        $longestValue = $value;
    }
}
var_export($longestValue);
```

Output:

```
'Walking the dog to the park'
```